# MediaWiki clientlogin won't accept logintoken

Tags: typescript, mediawiki

I'm attempting to use the *clientlogin* action for the MediaWiki api as shown below.

When I attempt to make the request like the api says to

> /wiki/api.php?action=clientlogin&format=json&logintoken={token}&username={username}&password={password}

I get the error that the *logintoken* needs to be in the request body. This led me to the resulting code below but it now returns the error that *logintoken* needs to be set. Any clue why this is?

**Side note:**
I have retrieved the username and password in another function that is passed in through the inputs map.

```
async function requestLogin(loginToken: string, inputs: {[key:string]: string}) {

    let loginRequest: string = "?action=clientlogin&format=json";
    let loginData: {[key:string]: string} = {
        'logintoken': loginToken
    };
    for (let key in inputs) {
        // place the key/value into the request
        loginData[key] = inputs[key];
    }

    console.log(loginData);
    const login = bent(state.url, 'POST', 'json');
    let loginResponse = await login(loginRequest, loginData);
    if ("error" in loginResponse) {
        console.log(loginResponse["error"]);
        console.log(loginResponse["error"]["info"]);
    } else {
        // Successfully logged in :)
        console.log(loginResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that some kind of Javascript-derived language? Please tag your questions with the language used so people with the relevant expertise can find it.

Comment: @Tgr Yes, it's Typescript, I'll tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are sending the body as a JSON. The legacy MediaWiki API takes data in either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` format. (I.e. the simplest way is to just move the query string from the URL to the body.) There's a REST API which takes JSON input but it's new, not well documented and only offers a limited set of functionality at this point.

Also, are you sure you need `action=clientlogin`? It's an API meant for building an interactive login interface on the client side; it does not work the way people tend to assume it would. The `action=login` is probably a better alternative.

Comment: I was previously using the `action=login` but looking at the API docs it warns:


"This action should only be used in combination with Special:BotPasswords; use for main-account login is deprecated and may fail without warning. To safely log in to the main account, use action=clientlogin."

Making me believe I would need to use the `action=clientlogin` because I'd like to use my main account to edit articles.

Comment: Your code would also fail without warning in the same scenarios (clientlogin would return the data for a captcha form or something like that, and the code is not prepared to handle it), the only difference is that it does not support [bot passwords](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords) either (which you *can* use with your main account).